# How to use 'def' to get an input value

Tags: python, global-variables, local, function

If I use global variables. I can write like this way.

```
while True:
    name_str = input('Please give me the file name:')
    if name_str == 'table.csv':
        break
    else:
        print('Bad file name, please try again.')
```

How to def a function and get input from this function?
Get users' input in the beginning function and call main function to get users' input.

```
def get_name(n):
    x = input('Please give me the file name:')
    ...
    ...

def main():
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Why not return `x` from `get_name`?

Comment: I can do that return part.I don't know how to make an input in def get_name():. If there anything other ways to call main() get input from def get_name()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have this in a file (test.py):

```
def get_input():
    return raw_input('get file: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_input()
```

And then call it:

$ python test.py

Note two things:

1. input() vs raw_input() -- input() is [not safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)
2. using idiom 'if **name** ...' for [script environment](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) instead of having main() function.

Comment: input() is only not safe prior to python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If your method is *gathering* the information from the user, you can write it this way:

```
def get_name():
    return input('Please give me the file name. ')
```

If your method is *parsing* information from the user, it would *accept* the file name as an argument and be written something like this:

```
def check_file_name(fname):
    if fname == 'table.csv':
        return True
    return False
```